# Can a old Redirect 301 from .htaccess be removed if the source url is marked as excluded in the Google Search Console?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, google-search-console

I'm cleaning up my huge `.htaccess` file which got bloated over the years.

There are many `Redirect 301`'s in my `.htaccess` file which are years old. I see few of the old/source urls in the `.htaccess`marked as excluded in the google search console. Now, is it safe to remove these entries in the `.htaccess`? Can I assume that these redirects are unnecessary now ?

Like say,

> .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 /xxxxx https://www.yyyyyy.com
```

Now, In `Google Search Console -> Index -> Coverage` report, I see the `/xxxxx` is marked as the **Excluded**. So, now am I good to remove the above entry from `.htaccess` as google already indexed a canonical version of it?